# Crystal connection

Tags: microcontroller, crystal

When I design my circuit, I'm confused and made the wrong connection. I connected my microprocessor to second pin instead of third pin of cyrstal. But I left the third pin blank. So when my circuit come from manufacturer, I can solder pins 2 and 3 and problem fix. Is this solution to work ? According to datasheet second pin must connect to ground.

This is datasheet.
https://www.mouser.com.tr/datasheet/2/905/c_NX3225SA_e-1317523.pdf

And my circuit.
[image]

*Capacitors connected to second pin.

Answer (score 1):

Pins 2 and 4 are connected to the crystal case. You will need to cut the trace to pin 2 and reconnect it to pin 3. That should work until you can fix the board layout.

For sure you will need to isolate pin 2 unfortunately. The case adds too much parasitic capacitance. Normally the case is grounded, you should also include this when you roll the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can short 2 & 3.

However I would check if 2 is not connected to the case. In that case I would prefer to remove the connection of 2 and the CPU.

Comment: Can you explain why a connection between 4 and 2 is important? What difference does it make?

Comment: I can not cut connection between second pin and cpu according to datasheet 2 and 4 are connected.

Comment: Yes, at zoom of 150% I noticed the very small print that 2 & 4 are connected to the case. If you can't, you can't. In which case my answer mirrors hacktasatic and I will delete it in a few minutes.

Comment: It looks like you have room to cut the trace to pin 2.  Can you edit your question with a bit wider view of your circuit board?  Things would have to be awfully tight to keep you from doing a cut & jump there.